# Неправильная работа шаблона компонента битрикс

Tags: битрикс, шаблоны

Перенес шаблон компонента с одного сайта на другой путем копирования папки с шаблоном, он отображается некорректно (не отображаются элементы). Почему так может быть? Может нужно выполнить ещё какие то действия?